# Backup Error (.bak)

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2014

I need to backup the database in SQL Server 2014.

When I am trying to do so, I am facing this problem which is not saving backup as a (`.bak`) extension.

And when I try to select (Files and filegroups) and then select (the database needed to be backed up) but nothing seems to work right.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For Backup component, click **Database**.

1. Either accept the default backup set name suggested in the Name text box, or enter a different name for the backup set.
2. Optionally, in the Description text box, enter a description of the backup set.
3. Choose the type of backup destination by clicking Disk, Tape or URL. To select the paths of up to 64 disk or tape drives containing a single media set, click Add. The selected paths are displayed in the Backup to list box.

To remove a backup destination, select it and click Remove. To view the contents of a backup destination, select it and click Contents.

OR

you can simply use T-SQL to achieve this:

To backup the database:

```
Use <your database name here>
BACKUP DATABASE <your database name here>
TO DISK = 'path where you want to  backup.bak';
```

To backup filegroup :

```
    Use <your database name here>
    BACKUP DATABASE <your database name here>
    FILEGROUP = 'name of the file group'
    TO DISK = 'path where you want to save backup.bak';
```

Answer (score 0):

1) select your database and press right-click , then choose tasks then [image]backup.
2) Then change the backup type to transaction log.[image]
3)Then press Add and click on the box (...)[image]
4) write the database name.bak in the (File name) and don't forget to write this extension (.bak)
5)Finally write ok 3 times it should work fine